# Removable Media Trigger Event

Tags: launcher, media

I created a shell script that copies files off of an SD card.

I then created a Unity Launcher (.desktop file) for that script.

Finally under System Settings -> Details -> Removable Media -> Photos I selected my Launcher.

Now when I insert an SD card my script runs.

Is there any way to pass to my script what drive (either the device name or mount point) triggered the launch?